# splitting hexadecimal value in mips

Tags: assembly, hex, mips

I am working on a project where I need to take values contained in a hexadecimal value and split it. I will have a register that contains a value, 0xAA00BBCC and need to split it into 3 different integers, AA, BB, and CC

For example:

if the value is: 0x88000232, I need to split it into 3 integers:
A: 88,
B: 02,
and C: 32.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hexadecimal is a serialization format for binary numbers.  You probably mean your registers hold binary integers with those hex values, because the number you gave takes 8 hex digits, which (in ASCII) takes 8 bytes to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of SRL and ANDI, but sometimes one of them is unnecessary. For example:

```
srl $t0, $a0, 8
andi $t0, $t0, 0xFF
```

This shifts the value so that the BB from 0xAA00BBCC is at the bottom (0x00AA00BB) and then the `andi` resets the bits that don't belong to that BB part.

When the shift count is 24, the `andi` is not needed. And of course shifting by 0 positions is not useful so in that case only the `andi` is needed.